# If $X$ is normally distributed, find a number $x_{0}$ such that $f\left(x\right)$

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

If $X$ is normally
distributed with $\mu=2$ , $\sigma=2$., find a number $x_{0}$ such that $f\left(x\right)$

a) $$P\left(X>x_{0}\right)=.10$$
My try:
$$Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$$ $$P\left(Z>\frac{x_{0}-2}{2}\right)=1-X=.10$$
Where $X=\frac{x_{0}-2}{2}$, solving for $X$,$$X=0.9$$
$$\frac{x_{0}-2}{2}=0.9$$ Checking the table values for the normal distribution $$x_{0}=3.8$$
b) $$P\left(X>-x_{0}\right)=.20$$
My try:
$$\frac{-x_{0}-2}{2}=0.8$$
$$x_{0}=-3.6$$
$$P\left(Z>\frac{-3.6-2}{2}\right)=1-2.8=-1.85=0.08851$$

Can you please provide me some feedback, for both solutions, I tried to check if the values are correct but I don't get the same value for b)?

Comment: So the expected value and the standard deviation are both $2$, such as $X\sim \mathcal N(2,4)$?

Comment: Yes it is like that: with $\mu=2$ , $\sigma=2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply the normal distribution function. The equation is $P(X>x_0)=1-P(X<x_0)$ (converse probability).

This is the same as $P(X>x_0)=1-\Phi\left(\frac{x_0-2}{2} \right)=0.1$. Here $\Phi\left(z\right)$ is the cdf of the normal distribution. Solving the equation for $x$. Adding $\Phi\left(\frac{x_0-2}{2} \right)$

$1=0.1+\Phi\left(\frac{x_0-2}{2} \right) \quad |-0.1$

$1-0.1=\Phi\left(\frac{x_0-2}{2} \right) \quad $

$0.9=\Phi\left(\frac{x_0-2}{2} \right) \quad $

Now we have to use the inverse function in order to isolate $x_0$.

$\Phi^{-1}\left(0.9\right) =\frac{x_0-2}{2} \quad $

Now you look at [a table](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Ersims/ma464/standardnormaltable.pdf) and look where the function is approximately $0.9$. This is at $\Phi\left(1.28\right)= .89973\approx 0.9$. So $\Phi^{-1}\left(0.9\right)=1.28$. The equation becomes

$$1.28=\frac{x_0-2}{2} \quad $$

Is it comprehensible up to here? If yes, then I think you can go on by yourself.

Comment: For b) converse probability also applies?

Comment: Yes. $P(X>-x_0)=1-P(X<-x_0)=1-\Phi\left( \frac{-x_0-2}{2}\right)$